# Insert Current User into Table Column Using BEFORE INSERT Trigger SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I want to insert the current user into the "created_by" column using a before insert trigger.

Here's what I have so far:

```
create or replace trigger course_fp_trg 
before insert on course 
begin
  :new.created_by := user;
end;
```

But I get the error "NEW or OLD references are not allowed in table level triggers"

How can I insert the current user into the "created_by" column of this table using a before insert trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make it a row level trigger by adding `FOR EACH ROW`.

```
create or replace trigger course_fp_trg 
before insert on course for each row
begin
  :new.created_by := user;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
create or replace trigger course_fp_trg 
before insert on course 
referencing old as old new as new
for each row
begin
  :new.created_by := user;
end;
```